# How do I identify which radio button was pressed using tkInter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning Python and have started exploring tkInter to develop simple GUI examples. My current exercise is to develop a set of buttons that act as switches representing discrete inputs. My problem is that when the `pin_state_change` is invoked after a button press I have no way of knowing which of the buttons was pressed?

Once I know which button is pressed I can then change the correct GPIO state.

After much googling I came across the `IntVar()` approach in tkInter and using a `get()` call I should be able to get the ID of the button that was pressed, but this is not working - the `print(var.get())` always prints 0 on the console, no matter which button I press.

```
from gpio_pin import gpio_pin_type
import tkinter as tk


gpio_pins_rb = []

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
var = tk.IntVar()
window = tk.Tk()

def pin_state_change():
    print(var.get())

def create_gui():

    window.title("GPIO V1 GUI")

    for radbut in range(0, 5):

        tk.Radiobutton(window, text ="GPIO " + str(radbut),value = "GPIO " + str(radbut), bg = "red", indicatoron = False, command = pin_state_change).grid(row = 5, column = radbut)

    window.mainloop()

def initialise_system(no_of_gpios):

    gpio_pins = []    

    for pin in range (0, no_of_gpios):
        gpio_pins.append(gpio_pin_type(pin, "discrete"))

        gpio_pins[pin].set(1)

        #print(gpio_pins[pin].get(), end =" ")

    return gpio_pins


def main():

    gpins = initialise_system(5)

    print(gpins[1].get())

    create_gui()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your `var` remains 0 because there is absolutely nothing in your code that will ever change it.  You need to pass `variable=var` to each of your Radiobuttons to connect them to the particular var.  You also need to use compatible types - either change the `value=` option to an int, or use a `StringVar`.

Answer (score 0):

Radiobuttons are connected in a group by having them share a tkinter variable. With that you don't need to know specifically which button was clicked, you just need to fetch the value of the associated variable.

```
tk.Radiobutton(window, variable=var, ...)
```

With the above, `var.get()` will always return the value of the currently selected radiobutton.

You have several other problems in your code. You are creating two instances of `Tk()` but you must have only one. Also, you are setting the radiobutton values to strings but you're later trying to convert those strings to integers. It's not clear if you need the integer or the string, but you've got to be consistent in how you use the value.

Here is a stripped-down version of your code to illustrate it working. I'm assuming you want the integer value rather than a string, so I've modified the code appropriately.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar()

def pin_state_change():
    print(var.get())

def create_gui():

    for radbut in range(0, 5):
        rb = tk.Radiobutton(
            root,
            variable=var,
            text ="GPIO " + str(radbut),
            value = radbut,
            bg = "red",
            indicatoron = False,
            command = pin_state_change
        )
        rb.grid(row = 5, column = radbut)

    root.mainloop()

def main():

    create_gui()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - your description is very clear!